# Updating matplotlib annotation position without redrawing all data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've essentially recreated the matlab data cursor on my custom pyplot figure tool. It allows dragging and left/right arrow key presses to update an annotation box's position along a line, etc. My problem comes from when there are a large number of lines. The data cursor still works, but dragging its position around is a nightmare and is extremely slow. The problem stems, I'm rather certain, from my canvas.draw() calls since it's redrawing the entire figure every time the data cursor moves.

I'm working towards implementing options like blit() and "restore_region()", but I'm having great difficulty implementing them. Can anyone provide even a shell of how to make this work? I can't include actual code due to the classification of the code itself, but I can give a small pseudo-code example.

```
def create_anno(self):
    # Do annotation creation stuff here
    self.background = self.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axis.bbox)

def key_press(self):
    self.figure.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
    # Do update position/text stuff here
    self.figure.canvas.blit(self.axis.bbox)
    self.figure.canvas.flush_events()
```

The key_press function is called normally, but the annotation box doesn't move anymore. Most examples use draw_artist() between their restore_region() and blit() calls, but annotation doesn't have that. I just want to update a little annotation box's position across a figure without having to redraw the entire axis. Any ideas?

Thanks!